# Current-time-label in Time column in recat big calendar

Tags: react-big-calendar

I have use timeSlotWrapper to show current time label in time column, but it is applying for event container also[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n478H.jpg).How to solve?

```
`const CustomTimeSlotWrapper = ({ children, value }) => {
 const slotTime=moment();
 const isCurrentTime = moment().isBetween(slotTime, slotTime.clone().add(30, 'minutes'), null, '[]');
  const currentTime = moment().format('h:mm A');
  return (
   <div >
  
  {children}
  {isCurrentTime && <div className="current-time-label">{currentTime}</div>}
   </div>
   );
  };

 .current-time-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F74969;
  } `
```